# how to block UI from coming up on softkeyboard display

Tags: android, keyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I am using same activity for multiple fragments. every fragment there is a searchview. Except home fragment in all other fragment we display listviews. In home fragment i have linear layouts to display some buttons and footer view. And when i type something in searchview in the home fragment it will display listview.i want to resize my screen when keyboard is up. So i have used below mentioned tag in manifest file for the actvity.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

It is wokring fine in all the fragments except home fragment. In home fragment when i tap on searchview(before typing.ie still displaying the buttons) the screen including the footer view is up. No issues with layout contains buttons. becuase it is scrollable. But topmost layout is not visible fully. Is it possible to stop it from pushing the footer layout to top in this fragment?

Comment: why resize, why not android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" will not allow to scroll up the listview to above the keyboard.